# To prove $A \rightarrow B \lor C$, is it sufficient to show $A \rightarrow B$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-writing

For an exercise, I must show by contrapositive that ($x \neq  0 \in \mathbb{Q}) \land y\notin \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow xy \notin \mathbb{Q}$.

Since the RHS of the contrapositive is a series of statements separated by the logical connector *or*, would it be sufficient to only prove the following: $ xy \in \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow y \in \mathbb{Q}$?

Thanks!

Comment: It would be sufficient if it were true, but it isn't.

Comment: Not only the case where $x=0$ but also other possibilities like $x\notin \Bbb Q$ such as $\sqrt{2}\cdot \sqrt{2}\in\Bbb Q$ but $\sqrt{2}\notin \Bbb Q$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, to prove $A \rightarrow B \vee C$, it is sufficient to prove $A \rightarrow B$ (as $B \rightarrow B \vee C$). However, you won't be able to prove $xy \in \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow y \in \mathbb{Q}$ as this statement is not true. (Take $y = \pi$, $x = \frac{1}{\pi}$.)

Answer (score 0):

Your title: "To prove $A \rightarrow B\lor C $ is proving $A \rightarrow B$ sufficient" has the answer "yes".

But one can not do so if $A$ and $\lnot B$ and $C$ in which case $A \rightarrow B\lor C $ is true but $A \rightarrow B$ is not.

What would be *equivalent* (not merely sufficient) would be $A \land \lnot C \rightarrow B$.

But your body question is actually "To prove $A \land \lnot B \rightarrow \lnot C$ is proving $C\rightarrow B$ sufficient" has the answer "yes".

But one can not do so if $\lnot A$ and $\lnot B$ and $C$ in which case $A \land \lnot B \rightarrow \lnot C$ is true but $C\rightarrow B$ is not.

As may be the case with $xy \in \mathbb Q \not \rightarrow y\in \mathbb Q$ if $x = 0$ or $x \not \in \mathbb Q$.

What would be equivalent would be $C \land A \rightarrow B$

If with case $xy \in \mathbb Q \land (x \ne 0; x \in \mathbb Q) \rightarrow y \in \mathbb Q$.  (As $y = xy/x \in \mathbb Q$)